# when I learn pwn, use gdb debug, but assembly return failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, gdb, stack-overflow

I'm learning pwn about stack overflow. I use gdb to debug a linux elf file.

Elf binary only turns on NX.

[image]

I execute stack overflow successfully.

But when execute

```
leave  
ret
```

I meet a error.

First arrived `leave`

[image]

you can see

[image]

step

[image]

error shows

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x8
```

I do not access memory at `0x8`.
Now $rbp is `0x0`, ubuntu check `$rbp+0x8` when `ret` execute?
why this happend?

My Environment

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-142-generic #168~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan 19 11:26:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which instruction exactly gave that fault?  You used `step` (`s`), not `stepi` (`si`), so GDB may have tried to step multiple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the instruction pointer points to `0x8` when you are overflowing the buffer. So the program tries to get to that location but there is no such location in the memory allocated for the binary. It would be better if you tell what the buffer size was and what was the amount of junk that you gave.

Thank You